# How to Echo JSON string

Tags: php, html, json

I want to echo/print a JSON string, here is what I have tried.

I have decoded as it returns associative array.

```
 $decoded = json_decode('{"Title": "The Cuckoos Calling",
                                "Author": "Robert Galbraith",
                                "Detail": {
                                "Publisher": "Little Brown"
                                }}', true/* returns Associative Array */);

                foreach ($decoded as $head => $inner) {

                    echo $head . ': </br>';
                }
```

It only prints...

```
Title: 
Author: 
Detail:
```

Here is what I want...

```
Expected Output :
Title  : The Cuckoos Calling
Author : Robert Galbraith
```

**EDIT:**

Its `print_r()` output is.

```
Array ( [Title] => The Cuckoos Calling [Author] => Robert Galbraith [Detail] => Array ( [Publisher] => Little Brown ) )
```

And `var_dump()` is

```
 array (size=3)
  'Title' => string 'The Cuckoos Calling' (length=19)
  'Author' => string 'Robert Galbraith' (length=16)
  'Detail' => 
    array (size=1)
      'Publisher' => string 'Little Brown' (length=12)
```

Comment: first check with `print_r($decoded);`

Comment: [possible duplicate of :][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597941/how-to-echo-json-in-php

or rather try. its a working code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you noticed that you are only printing the $key and not the value ???

```
foreach ($decoded as $head => $inner) {
    echo $head . ': '. $inner . '</br>';
}
```

this is what you need :

```
function arrayToUl($array)
{
    $out = "<ul>";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $value_string = $value;
        if (is_array($value))
            $value_string = arrayToUl($value);
        $out .= "<li>{$key} : {$value_string}</li>";

    }
    $out .= "</ul>";
    return $out;
}

echo arrayToUl($decoded);
```

Comment: I tried this..

It prints title and author....


But there is another array inside that associative array...

See my var_dump() output in my question.

Comment: Why do you iterate with a foreach ? Why not only echoing author and title ? How do you want to handle the "Detail" array ?

Comment: @UmairAyub what do you what to do with the inner array ? ignore it ? flatten it ? or what ???

Comment: @Exlord I want to print that too or ignore it... .. see the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

simply use [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
array_walk_recursive($decoded, function($key,$value) {
  echo $value.' :'.$key.'<br>';
});
```

**output**:

```
Title :The Cuckoos Calling
Author :Robert Galbraith
Publisher :Little Brown
```